# Issue formatting JSON array in PHP

Tags: php

Essentially I have the following conditionals that are made to assemble an array - the issue is the array it currently creating has too many objects.

```
$a = 1
$b = 2


if ($a == 1)){
$results[]['id'] = 5;
$results[]['reasons'] = "A issue";
}

if ($b == 1){
$results[]['id'] = 6;
$results[]['reasons'] = "B issue";
}

if ($b == 2){
$results[]['id'] = 6;
$results[]['reasons'] = "B issue";
}
)

$json = json_encode(array($results));
echo $json;
```

Current Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "reasons": "A issue"
  },
  {
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "reasons": "B issue"
  }
]
```

**What I need:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
     "reasons": "A issue"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
     "reasons": "B issue"
  }
]
```

How can this JSON Array be built correctly using the conditionals?

Comment: This may just be an example, but you should also try and combine and conditions that always generate the same JSON (`$b` is 1 or 2) to reduce duplication of code if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You use `$results[][$value]` which means push something to an array.

All you have to do is put the `$id` and the `$reason` in an array and push that array to your results, not each item individually:

```
$results[] = [
   'id' => 5,
   'message' => 'A issue'
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add one object of array to your array to do that. You're actually adding strings and numbers.

**CHANGE:**

```
$results[]['id'] = 5;
$results[]['reasons'] = "A issue";
```

**TO:**

```
$results[] = [
    'id' => 5,
    'reasons' => "A issue"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code like this:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;


if ($a == 1){
$results[] = ['id'=> 5, 'reasons' => 'A issue'];

}

if ($b == 1){
$results[] =['id'=> 6, 'reasons' => 'B issue'];

}

if ($b == 2){
$results[] =['id'=> 6, 'reasons' => 'B issue'];

}


$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```